# Second parameter of a functino called in a conditional?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a function to run through an array of questions and an array of answers. Then all I would have to do is call the function with the parameters adjusted each time.

```
let playerScore = 0;
let questions = ['What is the capital of Germany?', 'Who is coolest man 
in Bloominton, IL?'];
let answers = ['BERLIN', 'VANCE'];

let quiz = (questions, answers) => {
  let quizAnswer = prompt(questions);
   if (quizAnswer.toUpperCase === answers) {
    playerScore++;
    alert('That is correct!');
  } else {
     alert("I'm sorry, but that is not correct");
   };
 };

quiz(questions[0], answers[0]);
```

The conditional won't run correctly. The variable 'answers' calls properly until it's inside of the conditional statement. I'm assuming it has to do with scope. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `toUppercase()` is missing `()`, for a start.

Comment: wow. Thanks! I'm obviously a beginner at this. I was racking my brain super hard trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) is a function, not a property.

Following changes `answer` and `question` to singular so as not to be confused with the array names

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let questions = ['What is the capital of Germany?', 'Who is coolest man in Bloominton, IL?'];
let answers = ['BERLIN', 'VANCE'];

let quiz = (question, answer) => {
  let quizAnswer = prompt(question);
   if (quizAnswer.toUpperCase() === answer) {
    playerScore++;
    alert('That is correct!');
  } else {
     alert("I'm sorry, but that is not correct");
   };
 };

quiz(questions[0], answers[0]);
```

Comment: `prompt()` return value should be checked (will be null if the user chooses to cancel).